# Android jetpack How to start a separated work manager chain after specific work task of another chain

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-workmanager

I want to implement this scenario with jetpack workmanager chains:

- chain1 = A -> B -> c
- chain2 = Z (only one WorkRequest)
- chain3 = D -> E -> F

After chain1 is done, chain2 and chain3 start at the same time

I already found this in documentation, but it is the opposite of what I need.
[WorkContinuation.html#combine](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkContinuation.html#combine(java.util.List%3Candroidx.work.WorkContinuation%3E))

Answer (score 0):

When you chain a single set of work together, you use the [`then`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkContinuation.html#then(androidx.work.OneTimeWorkRequest)) that takes a single `OneTimeWorkRequest`. You can use the [`then`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkContinuation.html#then(java.util.List%3Candroidx.work.OneTimeWorkRequest%3E)) that takes **a list of `OneTimeWorkRequest`** to split the chain.

As per the [chaining work documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/chain-work):

> If you add a List of OneTimeWorkRequests, these requests can potentially run in parallel.

Leading to exactly the behavior you want.

```
val workManager = WorkManager.getInstance(myContext)

// Create all your work
val workA, workB, workC, workZ, workD, workE, workF

// Then build chain1
val chain1 = workManager.beginWith(workA)
    .then(workB)
    .then(workC)

// Now link in both Z and D
chain1.then(workZ, workD)
    .enqueue()

// There's nothing after Z, so there's no explict work
// you need to do for chain2

// Then build off of D to finish chain3
workManager.beginWith(workD)
    .then(workE)
    .then(workF)
    .enqueue()
```

Comment: @AmrooOs - so? WorkManager already handles application restarts for you.

Comment: Thank you for your response , But a possible work duplicate may occur. because the application may restart while work request still running.
i want to use below,but didn't work:

` workManager
            .beginUniqueWork(
                UNIQUE_WORK_NAME1,
                ExistingWorkPolicy.KEEP, workRequestA
            ).then(workRequestB).then(workRequestC).then(listOf(workRequestZ, workRequestD)).enqueue()`

Comment: yes WorkManager handle application restart but it didn't avoid duplicate work unless i use workManager.beginUniqueWork, which i tried but didn't work ,the last chine not fired .

Comment: It sounds like you are unconditionally enqueuing more work on application startup rather than checking if the work already exists (which will on the case where it gets interrupted by your application being killed and restarted) - it'll always be better to check your state if you just want to prevent concurrently running work. `KEEP` specifically just drops anything you enqueue if there's already any unique work with that name in the system (whether it is started or finished), so it probably isn't what you want.

Comment: you are right , i will try to make all work done in one chain , then use coroutines inside workRequestD to do the work of workRequestZ in parallel, plus using shared pref to check state of each work. i will post the solution later if it works. thank you again.